# Please help me to find the sum $\sum\limits_{n\geq1} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, integration, limits

I must show that $\sum\limits_{n\geq1} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}$ converges $\forall x \in {R}$. Then  if $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty f_n(x)$, I must prove that  $f(x)$ is continuous for $x\in [0, \pi]$  and  $\int\limits_0^\pi f(x)=2\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n-1)^3}$.

I used Weistrass M-test: $\sum\limits_{n\geq1} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}$ converges uniformly because $|\frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}|\le \frac{1}{n^2}, \forall x\in R$ and $\sum \frac {1}{n^2}$ converges.

I found somewhere that $f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$. Where does it come from? I don't understand. How $f(x)$ looks like? Without $f(x)$ I don't know how to prove the last equality from exercise:(

Later edit: If $ \sum\limits_{n\geq1}f_n\to f$ uniformly , then $f_n\to f$ (*punctual converges to* $f $- I hope this is correct translation) which means $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ when $n\to \infty ?$

I hope someone could help me again...

Comment: Convergence $\sum_{n\ge 1} f_n \to f$ can not imply $f_n\to f$, otherwise the series would be divergent.

Comment: This is a Clausen function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function

Comment: "converges pointwise to f" is the standard translation, but "punctual convergence" is perfectly comprehensible as the same thing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As you observed, by the Weierstrass M-test, the series converges uniformly.  Let 
$$f(x)=\sum_1^\infty \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}.$$
The functions $\sin(nx)/n^2$ are continuous, so their "sum" $f(x)$ is continuous.  (In general, if we do not have *uniform* convergence, but only *pointwise* convergence, the sum need not be continuous.)

The above result about continuity is causing you some confusion.  It is based on a theorem that says, or should say, that if $(f_n(x))$ is a **sequence** of continuous functions that converges uniformly to $f(x)$ in an interval, then  $f(x)$ is continuous.

To  apply the theorem to a **series** $\sum_{n \ge 1} g_n(x)$, we just let $f_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n g_k(x)$.  There is nothing new in this: convergence of infinite series is *defined* in terms of what happens to partial sums as $n$ goes to infinity.

The additional fact that is needed is that a series uniformly convergent on a finite interval can be integrated term by term on that interval.  So we need to calculate $\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2} dx$ and "add up."

More explicitly, 
$$\int_0^\pi \left(\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}\right)\,dx=\sum_{n \ge 1} 
\left(\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin(nx)}{n^2}\,dx\right).$$ 
(The above  *interchange* of the order of integration and summation is permitted because of the uniform convergence.  It can fail when we do not have uniform convergence.)

The integration is straightforward, for $\sin(nx)$ has $-\dfrac{\cos(nx)}{n}$ as an antiderivative.
Thus 
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin nx}{n^2}dx=\frac{1}{n^3}(-\cos(n\pi)+1).$$
If $n$ is even, $\cos(n\pi)=1$, so the integral is $0$, and contributes nothing to the ultimate sum.

If $n$ is odd, then $\cos(n\pi)=-1$, so the integral is $\dfrac{2}{n^3}$.
Since $n$ is odd, let $n=2m-1$. Then 
$$\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin nx}{n^2}dx=\frac{2}{(2m-1)^3}.$$
We conclude that
$$\int_0^\pi f(x) \;dx=\sum_1^\infty \frac{2}{(2m-1)^3}.$$
(In your post, the final variable of summation is $n$, but that makes no difference.)

**Interesting fact**: The sum that we end up with is closely related to $\sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{1}{n^3}$.  This last sum, also known as $\zeta(3)$, was proved to be irrational by Apery about $30$ years ago, using an elementary (but not easy) argument. It was one of those rare mathematical results that even gets reported in the mainstream press.

Comment: Thank you very much André Nicolas. The first part of your explanations helps me a lot.

Comment: In the last part of your explanation you wrote cos(nπ) instead of sin(nπ) :P Please change that. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: @Numlock: Thanks for spotting the inconsistency. It really is $\cos n\pi)$.  But the function I am integrating is $\sin(nx)$, and in a couple of places it was written as $\cos(nx)$. Fixed!  Someday I will write an answer free of things like that.

Comment: Perhaps for the sake of completeness we could include the the interchange of limits is justified by uniform convergence since we are integrating over a *finite* interval. Over infinite integrals, uniform convergence alone does not let us switch the limits. I have not been able to forget this detail since someone pointed out that my solution to a previous Putnam problem was incorrect because of this!

Comment: @Ragib Zaman: Thank you for the suggested change, I will try to change wording so that no one is led astray on a Putnam!

Answer (score 4):

Differentiate twice, get the series for $-\dfrac{1}{2 \tan\frac{x}{2}}$.  So now integrate this twice... Of course that is not elementary, but still...